# Publishing in QGIS Server (WMS, WFS-T) only certain map extent

Tags: qgis, wms, wfs, qgis-server, wfs-t

I am trying to publish a layer in WFS-T but I only want to publish a certain zone ( 10% of the whole layer ).

So I choose my extent in QGIS canvas and I go to Poryect Properties / OWS Server and I click in "Use the current view extension" and save project.

If I load the layers using WFS-T I can see the whole map and not the chosen extensión.

What am I missing?

[image]